# when click on button for change font size ma app get crash and say attemp a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, font-size

I have the Fragments with button and textview that Fill my Activity but when i clicking the Increase button for change size of font My App get crash and give me the following error. how can i change increase text font size with button click?

MyFragment

```
package com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.ListViewPages.Page1.ListActivity1_p1;


public class My2Fragment extends Fragment {
    private int page3;
    private String text3;
    private TextView txtView3;
    private int f = 20;

public static My2Fragment newInstance(int page,String text) {

    My2Fragment myFragment = new My2Fragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("someInt",page);
    b.putString("text", text);
    myFragment.setArguments(b);
    return myFragment;
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        page3 = getArguments().getInt("someInt");
        text3 = getArguments().getString("text");
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvFrag3);
        tvLabel.setText(text3 );
    }
}

public My2Fragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_my, container, false);

    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag1);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag3);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag4);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag5);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag6);
    Button btnIncreas  = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFIncr);
    btnIncreas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtView3.setTextSize(f+2);

        }
    });
    Button btnDicreas  = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFDicr);
    btnDicreas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            txtView3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,f-2);

        }

});

    Button btnHome  = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
    btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentH = new Intent(My2Fragment.this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentH);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.ListViewPages.Page1;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.My2Fragment;
import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.My3Fragment;
import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.My4Fragment;
//import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.My5Fragment;
import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.MyAnotherFragment;
import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.MyFragment;
import com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.R;

public class ListActivity1_p1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TextView txtView5;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_activity1_p1);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));



    }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = MyAnotherFragment.newInstance(i,getString( R.string. title_list1_intro_s),0x7f020040);

//                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity1_p1.this,"case 0 running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(i,getString( R.string.title_list1_intro_2));

//                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity1_p1.this,"case 1 running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                     fragment = My2Fragment.newInstance(i, getString(R.string.title_list1_intro2_1));
//                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity1_p1.this,"case 2 running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = My3Fragment.newInstance(i, getString(R.string.title_list1_intro2_1));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = My4Fragment.newInstance(i, getString(R.string.title_list1_intro2_1));
                    break;
//                case 5:
//                    fragment = My5Fragment.newInstance(i, getString(R.string.title_list1_intro2_1));
//                    break;


            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

    }
```

Error

```
10-10 00:04:43.718    3556-3556/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari, PID: 3556
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference
            at com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari.My2Fragment$1.onClick(My2Fragment.java:65)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-10 00:04:43.719    1245-1513/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari/.ListViewPages.Page1.ListActivity1_p1
10-10 00:04:43.724    1245-1293/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
10-10 00:04:44.233    1245-1263/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{37eba443 u0 com.miracle.royapoldari.royapoldari/.ListViewPages.Page1.ListActivity1_p1 t147 f}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code you get reference from 5 fragment and give to one textView this and when you want change text size program does not find which fragment should change size font and return null .
change this code to

```
txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag1);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag3);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag4);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag5);
    txtView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag6);
```

to for example of frag1

```
txtView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFrag1);
```

in onCreateView method of each fragment get reference of that text View to specfic textView of same class of layout